# Isometric immersion of $\mathbb H^2$ into $\mathbb R^\infty$ built by Bieberbach

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometric-immersion

I'm analyzing the following isometric immersion of $(\mathbb H^2,g_D)$ in $(\ell^2,g_\infty)$ given by $f(x,y)=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{2m-1},x_{2m},\dots)$ with
\begin{align}\label{5.1}
    x_{2m-1}=\color{red}{2}\operatorname{Re}\frac{(x+iy)^m}{\sqrt{m}},\quad x_{2m}=\color{red}{2}\operatorname{Im}\frac{(x+iy)^m}{\sqrt{m}},\quad m=1,2,\dots
\end{align}
I tried to check that it really is an isometric immersion, but I cannot calculate $f^*g_{\mathbb R^\infty}=g$, some metric $g$, or give it shape, I have tried to do it by means of its polar representation but I have gotten confused without reaching anything concrete. Any ideas how to attack this problem?

[Here](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?type=pdf&pid=com-001:1932:4::24) I leave the original document.

Comment: What do you denote by $\mathbf{R}^\infty$? I understand it consists of certain sequences, but with which condition and which norm/distance, and I don't know what you denote by $dx_m^2$.

Comment: From the context, I think, ${\mathbb R}^\infty$ means $\ell_2$ and $dx_i$ denotes the linear functional on $\ell_2$ defined by $dx_i((x_1, x_2,....))=x_i$. Your notation $f^*g_{\mathbb R^\infty}=\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty dx_m^2$ is horrifying. What you mean is that you define the standard inner product on $\ell^2$, treat it as a Riemannian metric $g$ and take its pull-back by $f$.

Comment: Cross-posted at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288146/isometric-immersion-of-bierbebach. As a general rule, you should avoid such simultaneous cross-posting in order to avoid duplication of efforts. Post your question on one site (say, MSE, wait a week or so and if there is no satisfactory answer, make a note of cross-posting and post on the other site (say, MO).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I understand, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm going to write how I have attacked it, I don't like it but maybe someone else has a more pleasant solution.

Comment: Apart from the typo in the last line of your computation (should be just $(1-x^2-y^2)^{2}$), this is the standard formula for the hyperbolic metric on the unit disk.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, actually, the metric of the Poincaré disk is $g_{D}=4\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1-(x^2+y^2))^2}$, but multiplying everything by a constant can fix this fact. A query I know that if the pullback $f^*g_{\mathbb R^2}=M g_{\mathbb H^2}$ then the image is a surface of curvature $-1/M$, it is easy to prove it by the Gauss' formula but in the $n-$dimensional case, for example, $f^*g_{\mathbb R^2}=M g_{\mathbb H^2}$ could be proved.

Comment: Technically, this is an isometric embedding into $\ell^2$ rather than ${\mathbb R}^\infty$ (the $\ell^2$ metric is not well-defined on the latter space).

Comment: You are right now I am editing it so that everything is understood, except that due to a great abuse of notation I put $\mathbb R^\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few tries I got the following:

Instead of taking real variable I take complex variable, that is let $z_m=\dfrac{\color{red}{2}z^m}{\sqrt{m}}$, donde $z_m=x_{2m-1}+ix_{2m}$. Then $dz_m=\color{red}{2}\sqrt{m}z^{m-1}dz$, thus
\begin{align*}
\varphi^*g_\infty&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty dx_{m}^2\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty (dx_{2m-1}^2+dx_{2m}^2)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty |dz_m|^2\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\color{red}{4}m|z|^{2(m-1)}|dz|^2\\[2mm]
&=\color{red}{4}|dz|^2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m|z|^{2(m-1)}\\[2mm]
&=\color{red}{4}\frac{|dz|^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}\\[2mm]
&=\color{red}{4}\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1-(x^2+y^2))^2}\\
&=g_D
\end{align*}